# How to generate raw data and create a jpeg using libjpeg?

Tags: c, jpeg, libjpeg

I'm practicing using the libjpeg library for a separate project, and I just wanted to generate a blue 100x100 jpeg image file utilizing libjpeg. I followed each step in their documentation, and I get a segmentation fault at `jpeg_finish_compress()`. I've utilized gdb to dig deeper into what's happening, and I'm having issues seeing what happens between the initial call to the function and the next step (within `jpeg_finish_compress()`). Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "jpeglib.h"

int height = 100;
int width = 100;
int i, j;

int main() {
    //init the image
    unsigned char image[height][width][3];
    for(i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            image[i][j][0] = 0x0;
            image[i][j][1] = 0x0;
            image[i][j][2] = 0xFF;
        }
    }


    //Create compression objects
    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
    struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;

    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);

    //Choose a destination and add error handling
    FILE *outfile = (FILE*) malloc(sizeof(FILE));
    char* filename = "test.jpeg";
    if(outfile == fopen(filename, "wb")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, outfile);

    //Compression parameters
    cinfo.image_width = width;
    cinfo.image_height = height;
    cinfo.input_components = 3; //RGB. 1 if grayscale
    cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB; //Could be JCS_GRAYSCALE also
    //Note: There are other compression parameters, but for most purposes, you can use:
    jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);

    //DO the compression
    jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);

    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1]; //pointer to a row with 12-bit precision

    while(cinfo.next_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {
        row_pointer[0] = *image[cinfo.next_scanline];
        jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
    }
    
    jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
    fclose(outfile); //close the file, responsibly
    
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
}
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I've structures the `image` variable, but it also could be that I'm using the library incorrectly. What exactly does `jpeg_finish_compress` do, and how can I get a jpeg from a set of RGB data?

Comment: https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg/blob/master/example.c

Comment: Thank you. This also follows the documentation provided [in the libjpeg-turbo repo](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/main/libjpeg.txt), which is what I followed. The only difference in `example.c` is that they set some optional parameters for the image (I just left it at `jpeg_set_defaults()`), and they seem to scan 3 rows at a time instead of 1. Are there vital differences you notice, that I'm missing?

Comment: Why not use their code to start with? If that works and yours doesn't then you have found some clues. Similarly, if they both don't work then you will also have found something

Comment: I will report back with what I find. At the moment it seems the version they have is different than mine.